# In node.js when using commonly used Async wrapper used to catch and forward errors where is (req, res, next) coming from?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, error-handling

**Environment:** Node.js, Express

Valeri Karpov, the creator and lead maintainer of Mongoose built a simple and widely used async wrapper used to catch and forward errors to the default Express error handler.

You can read about his error handler here, [The 80/20 Guide to Express Error Handling](https://thecodebarbarian.com/80-20-guide-to-express-error-handling)

This is the pattern he uses.

```
function wrapAsync(wrappedRoute) {

  return function(req, res, next) {

    wrappedRoute(req, res, next).catch(next);

  };

}
```

`wrapAsync` is used to wrap an async route like this,

```
exports.homePage = wrapAsync(async function(req, res) {
    
    let myVariable = await accessSomethingRemote();

    res.render('homepage', { myVariable });

});
```

Inside `wrapAsync` the line referenced below makes perfect sense.  Async functions return a promise and `.catch()` can be added to a promise to catch errors.  `next` forwards errors to the default Express error handler.

```
wrappedRoute(req, res, next).catch(next);
```

However I don't fully understand the mechanics of the line above it.

```
return function(req, res, next) {
```

**Question:** Where did the `req, res, next` come from?  They aren't declared inside `wrapAsync` nor are they explicitly passed in as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function(req, res, next)` is callback function. It's supposed to be called somewhere else, not in this snippet. In case of Express it's called by Express itself on a request with respective arguments, `req, res, next`.